# WSH on win98, is there a way can get user input with jscript?

Tags: wsh, windows-98

I'm writing `wsh` script with ‍‍`JScript` and got null from "WScript.StdIn", maybe the script engine too old or something wrong. is there another way to get user input?

PS: the computer doesn't have the internet and can't install any software from any kind of media.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read this page to find How do you ask a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And you are running the script with cscript.exe in a console/terminal?